# What happens to questions that don't have an answer?

Tags: support, questions

I mean, for example when the problem presented is actually a bug in the used technology.

Should someone answer it with the fact that it is a bug and maybe show the version from which that bug is no longer present, or should a moderator close the question with no answer given but with comments to the question showing that it is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the answer to the question is that there is a bug in the specific version, then that's the answer.

Why do you think that's an invalid answer?

It most certainly is a valid and good answer.

Comment: I agree with you, but most users are reticent to answer in such way.

Comment: @nighthawk702 _most_ users? How did you determine that?

Comment: "It's a bug" isn't so great, but "It's a bug, here's the issue on the project's bug tracker, it's fixed in version Y but if you're stuck on version X here's the suggested workaround: [code block]" is very helpful.

Comment: @canon I said that because I keep running into questions that have no answer but there is a good explanation about such a bug in the comments.